# Add a column in SQL with row count in Hive or BigQuery

Tags: hive, google-bigquery

I have a table such as

```
with temp_table as (
select 'john1', 100
union all
select 'john2', 500
union all
select 'john3', 700
union all
select 'john4', 800
union all
select 'john5', 200
union all
select 'john6', 600
union all
select 'john7', 300
)
select * from temp_table
```

and the data looks like -

```
john1,100
john2,500
john3,700
john4,800
john5,200
john6,600
john7,300
```

I would like to add one more column to this table which tells me the number of records for the entire table. For instance, current table has total number of records as `7`. So my output should look something like -

```
john1,100,7
john2,500,7
john3,700,7
john4,800,7
john5,200,7
john6,600,7
john7,300,7
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Can this be achieved without a `join` operation?

Note - This is a sample data but in reality the table can be quite big( > 5M records)

Answer (score 3):

Using hive `window` function **count(*) with over** clause and **won't** specifying any `partition by and order by clauses`.

```
  WITH temp_table AS (
  SELECT 'john1' name, 100 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john2', 500 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john3', 700 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john4', 800 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john5', 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john6', 600 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john7', 300
   ) 
  select *,count(*) over() count from temp_table;
```

**Output:**

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------+--+
| temp_table.name  | temp_table.value  | count  |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+--+
| john1            | 100               | 7      |
| john7            | 300               | 7      |
| john6            | 600               | 7      |
| john3            | 700               | 7      |
| john2            | 500               | 7      |
| john5            | 200               | 7      |
| john4            | 800               | 7      |
+------------------+-------------------+--------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

Below examples for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp_table AS (
  SELECT 'john1' name, 100 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john2', 500 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john3', 700 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john4', 800 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john5', 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john6', 600 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john7', 300
), totals AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) total_count FROM temp_table
)
SELECT *
FROM temp_table, totals
```

or

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp_table AS (
  SELECT 'john1' name, 100 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john2', 500 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john3', 700 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john4', 800 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john5', 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john6', 600 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'john7', 300
)
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp_table) total_count
FROM temp_table
```

My preference would be the first one

Both returns below result

```
Row name    value   total_count  
1   john1   100     7    
2   john2   500     7    
3   john3   700     7    
4   john4   800     7    
5   john5   200     7    
6   john6   600     7    
7   john7   300     7
```

Comment: certainly solution 1 looks good but does it mean it will perform a cross join ?

Comment: In reality - yes it is a cross join with single row dataset. And what is bad here is not a cross join itself, it will be transformed into map-join and will execute fast, but `total_count` dataset will be executed separately as a additional full scan. So, table will be scanned twice. One - for total_count, second - normal scan+cross join(fast map join during reading of the table). Using analytic count allow to eliminate extra scan at all. Please fix me If I'm wrong